# Error al intentar enviar mail PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Estoy tratando de generar un envío de mail por una cotización pero al enviar me lanza el siguiente error:

> Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

He estado investigando a cual puede ser el inconveniente y no he encontrado algo que me lo solucione mas que borrar la línea

> $mail->IsSMTP();

pero tampoco lo soluciona.
Dejo el código

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require '../PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require '../PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';

session_start();
require '../database.php';
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

try {

  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
  //$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
  $mail->IsSMTP(); //checkear
  $mail->Host = EMAIL_HOST;
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = EMAIL_USERNAME;
  $mail->Password = EMAIL_PASSWORD;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
  $mail->Port = EMAIL_PORT;

  $mail->setFrom( EMAIL_USERNAME,"Mailer");
  $mail->addAddress($_POST['mail']);

  $mail->FromName = 'Ferretería';   
  $mail->IsHTML(true);                          
  $mail->Subject = 'Cotización';            
  $mail_body = "blablabla";

}
```

En mi archivo de conexión a la bdd declaro las configuraciones del correo

```
//email
define("EMAIL_HOST","dtcwin105.ferozo.com");
define("EMAIL_USERNAME","cotizaciones@yo.com");
define("EMAIL_PASSWORD","****"); //contraseña server
define("EMAIL_PORT",465);
```

Answer (score 0):

Es muy difícil saber que pueda ocurrir. Te paso mi Snippet con el que envío mis mails en una App. Mira si te funciona y mira que puede ser el error.

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(600);
    // estos estan en la misma carpeta
    require_once 'class.phpmailer.php';
    require_once 'class.smtp.php';

    function sendMail($para, $asunto, $cuerpo, $copiaA='', $carpetaAdjunto='', $archivoAdjunto='', $respondeA=''){

        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'myMail@gmail.com';
        $mail->Password = 'myAppPassFromGoogle';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->Port = 465;
        $mail->setFrom('myMail@gmail.com', 'MyFrom');
        $mail->AddAddress($para);

        if(!empty($respondeA)) $mail->AddReplyTo($respondeA, $alias);

        if (!empty($copiaA)) foreach($copiaA as $email => $name) $mail->AddCC($email, $name);

        $mail->Subject = $asunto;
        $mail->AltBody = 'Para ver el mensaje , por favor utilice un visor de correo electronico compatible con HTML!';
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Body = $cuerpo;

        if(!empty($carpetaAdjunto) && !empty($archivoAdjunto)) $mail->AddAttachment($carpetaAdjunto.$archivoAdjunto, $archivoAdjunto);

        if (!$mail->Send()) {
            return "Error de envío de Email: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            exit;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Nunca me ha fallado, me comentas por favor.